# IIS: web.config redirect to another url preserving the original one in the address bar

Tags: asp.net, iis, redirect, asp-classic, url-rewriting

I'm trying to understand how to do this, but seems very complicated (at least for someone like me having no experience with IIS but only Apache). I'm porting a website from Linux to a Windows server, and on linux server I have an .htaccess that helps me rewriting urls to hide pages and arguments:

RewriteRule ^store/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ http://www.domain.com/store/$1/ [R]

RewriteRule ^store/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/$ http://www.domain.com/pages/store.asp?name=$1

RewriteRule ^store/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ http://www.domain.com/store/$1/$2/ [R]

RewriteRule ^store/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/$ http://www.domain.com/pages/store.asp?name=$1&page=$2

So that when someone visits http://www.domain.com/store/client1/ is visiting http://www.domain.com/pages/store.asp?name=client1 (and so on with up to 4 arguments), but in the browser addressbar the url shown is still http://www.domain.com/store/client1/

I can't find my way to do the same on IIS 7...I made something like below:

```
            <rule name="Rule 5">
                <match url="^store/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.com/store/{R:1}/" redirectType="Found" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Rule 6">
                <match url="^store/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.com/pages/store.asp?name={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Found" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Rule 7">
                <match url="^store/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.com/store/{R:1}/{R:2}/" redirectType="Found" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Rule 8">
                <match url="^store/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.com/pages/store.asp?name={R:1}&amp;page={R:2}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Found" />
            </rule>
```

This works for redirecting, so if I call www.domain.com/store/arg1/arg2/ I'm visiting www.domain.com/pages/store.asp?name={R:1}&page={R:2} , but in the browser addressbar I see the redirected address store.asp?name={R:1}&page={R:2} instead of the original www.domain.com/store/arg1/arg2/ , that instead what I need.

Is there a way to do this? I spent already several hours without a working solution...

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using an action of type `Redirect`, use `Rewrite`.  See this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2008/09/02/iis7urlrewriteseo.aspx) for more information.  This will rewrite the URL on the server to the one that you desire instead of redirecting the browser to a new URL.

Comment: Is there a way to persist the rewrite/redirects listed in the web.config across new builds/deployments using IIS?